# Cupy structure array subscript

Tags: cupy

How do I subscript a structured cupy array. I can't find the document about it...

```py
arr = cp.zeros(shape=(100,), dtype=cp.dtype([('t', '<f4'), ('tri', '<i4'), ('u', '<f4'), ('v', '<f4')]))

# numpy...
arr[...]['tri']

# cupy
????
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, CuPy does not support structured arrays. In fact, only boolean and numeric ones are listed as the supported data types in the [Overview documentation](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/overview.html).